# Redirect to "next" after Google Login. {Flask}

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, flask-login

Needing a little help in here:

Context: I am able to log in using email no problem. Redirect and url_for working flawlessly. 
When I login with google, though... It is logging in, but not redirecting, thus, not reloading the page, not showing the logout button and so on.

relevant code:
    python flask authorized login is "http://localhost:5000/oauth2callback":
    **btw: I know I shouldn't use google's id, I am still testing it.**

```
@app.route('/oauth2callback/<id>/<nome>/<email>', methods=['POST'])
def oauth2callback(id, nome, email):

   #print(f'o ID é {id}, o nome é {nome} e o email é {email}')
   try:

       if User().query.filter_by(email = email).first():
           usuario_google = User().query.filter_by(email = email).first()
           print(usuario_google)
           login_user(usuario_google)
           print('usuario logado')
           return redirect(url_for('home', next=request.url))
       else:
           sessao_google = User(username=email, email=email, nome=nome)
           senhas_google = Senha(senha='')
           db.session.add(sessao_google)
           db.session.commit()
           db.session.add(senhas_google)
           db.session.commit()
           print('Registrado')
           return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))

   except Exception as e:
       raise redirect(url_for('login'))
   finally:
       pass
   return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

I will add javascript just in case:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {

    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var xhttps = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var novaurl = 'http://localhost:5000/oauth2callback/'+profile.getId()+'/'+profile.getName()+'/'+profile.getEmail();
    console.log(novaurl)
    xhttps.open('POST', novaurl);
    xhttps.send();

}
```

Thank you for any ideas/help.